# Catch POST response from API with 302 status

Tags: php, http-post, http-status-code-302

I am trying to catch POST response send to me by external API.

The problem is that POST array is completely empty while I can check in firebug that browser recieved it but with codes 302 FOUND and second (with same body) with code 307 TEMPORARY REDIRECT:

[image]

Is there any way to grab this data inside my script or is this something wrong with server re-directions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CURL library, there are two options that help with your case:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
```

This returns the response header including the status code. You can see whether 302 is returned.

Or you can simply follow the redirect

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
```

Edit: sorry just saw you were doing this on the client side.

If this is an AJAX call, you can get the status code in the raw XHR object.

Comment: CURL is used only to generate payment link (from my side). When this payment is processed and accepted on the external payment site (dotpay,pl here) this site is making redirection and sends this data back. And its not an AJAX call. Can't do much more.

Comment: Can you post directly to the redirected link? Sometimes the 302 is simply an http -> https rewrite.

Comment: If you mean it - im getting data from this url https://ssl.dotpay.pl/test_fake/provider_pekao24/peo_pay/